# getting gateway timeout while executing a stored procedure via jdbc

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, struts2

I am using a struts2 framework which is basically like:-

```
ActionClass
execute
{
    call function in business class which returns an object and store this object in session
    redirect to jsp
}

BusinessClass
function()
{
    sysout("start");
    call a stored procedure via jdbc //this procedure returns 40 cursors and takes 6,7 mins to execute
    call setter methods of object and return object
    sysout("end");
}
```

JSP

The problem is that the procedure is taking a lot of time to execute and after that its called again and again because i am getting the sysouts "start"again and again.Finally,I see a gateway timeout error even adding session timeout in web.xml.If i dont put session timeout in web.xml then its throwing null pointer exception in action class while storing the object in session.Also,This problem is happening only after i deployed the code in unix server.In local,its working fine.I am using Tomcat 6.0 as web container.Can someone please explain why the procedure is called many times even though there is no looping.Is it somehow related to the fact that the procedure is returning 40 cursers.

Comment: Please rearrange your question.