# Correct Way to Run Stored Procedure In MSSQL Via JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to run a Stored Procedure in MSSQL via jdbc. The way I see it I have two options:

```
Connection conn = //Code that I know gets the correct connection
Statement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(request.query);
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(request.query);
```

Using this the query runs fine but the code throws an exception: `"Error: The statement did not return a result set."`

Or

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(request.query);
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Which does the same thing. Are these essentially doing the same thing under the hood? I know I could use `stmt.executeUpdate()` but I want to get a `ResultSet` back so I can do post processing.

Which way is correct? And what can I do to guarantee a `ResultSet` is returned?

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848074/getting-gateway-timeout-while-executing-a-stored-procedure-via-jdbc) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement/10804730#10804730) question and the answers were not effective/applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a stored procedure you should use a [CallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html). Note that you need to use the `{call ...}` syntax, something like this:

```java
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call procedure_name}");
ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
```